# Como enviar arquivos para um site estático no S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, amazon-aws

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em NodeJs utilizando o SDK da AWS. Resumindo o código cria um bucket, atribui as políticas de segurança para permitir o acesso público, e o habilita para sites estáticos porem, quando envio os arquivos via SDK ao acessar o endereço do site o conteúdo é baixado para o PC e não carregado no browser.

Obs: se os arquivos forem enviados diretamente pelo console da AWS o site funciona corretamente.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como posso resolver esse problema? Fiz várias pesquisas e até agora não consegui encontrar a solução.

```js
exports.createObject = (req, res) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const s3 = new S3Client({
            region: req.body.region
        })

        async function run() {

            try {

                const indexHTML = path.resolve('exPages', 'index.html')
                let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(indexHTML)

                let params = {
                    Bucket: req.body.bucket,
                    Key: path.basename(indexHTML),
                    Body: fileContent,
                }

                _Display.line()
                console.log(chalk.blueBright('Request - Upload files'))
                _Display.line()
                let data = await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(params))
                console.log(chalk.gray('Upload complete'))
                console.log('')
                console.log('', data)
                resolve(data)

            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Erro', error)
                reject(error)
            }
        }
        run()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Na hora de fazer o upload das imagens você precisa configurar o `ContentType` como `image/jpeg`, senão elas sobem como `binary/octet-stream` e não se comportam como você deseja.

```js
let params = {
    Bucket: req.body.bucket,
    Key: path.basename(indexHTML),
    Body: fileContent,
    ContentType: "image/jpg",
}
```

EDIT:

#### Habilitando hospedagem estatica no S3:

Vc precisa ir na aba **Properties** dentro do bucket e la embaixo em **Static website hosting** habilitar a hospedagem estatica.

Entao seus arquivos html com permissao publica de leitura serao acessiveis em: https://{**seu-bucket**}.s3-{**sua-regiao**}.amazonaws.com/{**seu-arquivo**}

---

referencia: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html

Comment: Leo, os arquivos que estão sendo enviados na verdade são do tipo html. Passei no Content Type "text/html" porem o problema continua

Comment: Putz, desculpa. Eu entendi que vc queria carregar os assets. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Leo, primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda. Descobri que havia um erro de digitação em ContentType: "text/html"